# Hubspot - Responsive design

Tags: mobile, content-management-system, responsive-design, hubspot

Is it possible to make a responsive layout for a website in HubSpot?

I have never worked with HubSpot, Therefore I would prefer to know first if it is possible.

If that's the case, could you give me a idea of how this is done? 
You don't need to write a whole manual : P
The website should be good looking on mobile.
Mobile.CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm currently a developer at HubSpot.

Yes, responsive UIs with HubSpot are completely possible. [Currently it's not super-easy](http://forums.hubspot.com/discussion/40555), but the new Content platform that we're working on will make this *much* easier. The good news is that you can already use the new template builder (and/or [templates from the Marketplace](https://marketplace.hubspot.com/templates)) for your landing pages and they're automagically responsive and mobile-friendly.

- [How to enable mobile optimization for a HubSpot site](http://help.hubspot.com/articles/How_To_Doc/How-to-enable-mobile-optimization-for-a-HubSpot-site)
- [How to optimize your website for mobile](http://help.hubspot.com/articles/Best_Practice/How-to-optimize-your-website-for-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

I built a site on Hubspot for a client who wanted me to mimic this Wordpress Theme:
http://themeforest.net/item/sterling-responsive-wordpress-theme/2320578

I got it all working nice. The site is not live yet so I can't show you that but it works just like the Sterling demo.

Hubspot already has a mobile.css file. Just as you add to/override Hubspot's css by making a custom.css file, you can make a mobile.css file to add to/override Hubspot's default mobile settings.

You should be able to find the mobile.css file through your browser's developer tools.

I use chrome. So... Inspect Element > Click on the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin Bos you can do any work on hubspot we can try anything related to web, some have some restrictions, but it is best CRm source